# How to find the residue of $\frac{\mathrm{e}^{z}}{\sin(2\mathrm{i}z)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Most of the time I deal with questions which asked me to find poles, e.g.,
$$
\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x+1} \quad\text{and}\quad \dfrac{x}{(x-i)(x-1)} \;,
$$
which I can find the poles and residue easily.

But this time round, if the question asks me to find poles of 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{z}}{\sin(2\mathrm{i}z)}
$$
at first glance I know it's gonna be $z=n\mathrm{i}\pi$ where $n$ is an integer.

So, for this case is the residue just $\mathrm{e}^{n\mathrm{i}\pi}$? I doubt my answer because when I check using the Wolfram residue calculator, it gives $\dfrac{-\mathrm{i}(-1)^n}{2}$ which I have no idea how it did it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the poles are all of order one, the residues at the poles $z = \frac{1}{2}n\pi i$ (note the $1/2$) are given by $$ \lim_{z\to \frac{1}{2}n\pi i}(z-\frac{1}{2}n\pi i)\frac{e^z}{\sin(2iz)}.$$ To evaluate this limit you just need to Taylor expand $\sin(2iz)$ at $z = \frac{1}{2}n\pi i.$ We have $$ \left.\frac{d}{dz} \sin(2iz)\right|_{z=\frac{1}{2}n\pi i} = 2i\cos(2iz)\Big|_{z=\frac{1}{2}n\pi i} = 2i\cos(n\pi)$$ so the residue is $$ \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}n\pi i}}{2i\cos(n\pi)}.$$ For $n=2m$ even (which correspond to the poles you didn't forget about) this reduces to $$ \frac{e^{m\pi i}}{2i\cos(2m\pi)} = -\frac{i}{2}e^{m\pi i} = -\frac{i}{2}(-1)^m$$ which agrees with what Wolfram gave you.

Comment: hi @spaceisdarkgreen , thanks for your reply but can I ask why is the pole z=pini/2?? Actually when do we need to differentiate poles?? Because so far I have not taught about this yet..

Comment: I think about it actually z=pini/2,z=0 and z=niπ are the poles?? but why is z=pini/2 used instead??

Comment: @john The poles are at $z=\pi i n /2$ because that's where $\sin(2iz) = 0.$ All I was doing with the derivative was computing the first order taylor expansion of $f(z) = \sin(2iz)$ at $\pi in/2$ $$ f(z) \approx (z-\frac{1}{2}n\pi i)f'(\frac{1}{2}n\pi i) $$ in order to evaluate that top limit. If it's easier to see, I pretty much just used L'Hospital's rule on the limit.

Comment: The poles are $0$, $\pm \frac{1}{2}\pi i,$ $\pm \pi i,$ $\pm \frac{3}{2}\pi i,$ 
$\pm 2\pi i,$ etc, which are exactly the numbers that can be written $\frac{1}{2}n\pi i$ for integer $n.$

Comment: @ spaceisdarkgreen i see, thanks!